# How to prevent my single instance application from getting focus

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments, single-instance

I have found several solutions for creating a single instance WinForms application.  I am using C# and I currently have three working versions.  But, each version is missing a feature I need.

The program has to run only once, update it's view with the new command arguments (displays a file), and NOT gain focus when this happens.

1. The version where I added a reference to the VB dll gets updated with the new document I want to load, but it gets focus.  Some examples of this have a line that explicitly tells the window to go to the front of the line.  My code does not have this.  My code is very similar to the first example in [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).
2. The mutex version stops when there is already a version running.  (I haven't tried combining versions yet to get a handle on the running instance.)  My code is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147/what-is-the-correct-way-to-create-a-single-instance-application).
3. And, the named instance version does not get focus (good) but does not recognize the new command line arguments.  My code resembles [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/702830/Single-Instance-Form-Application-in-Csharp).

Each one of these items has a solution that does something I need, just not all of them together.

Comment: How do you have a "single" instance *and* have a view updated and not gain focus?  That is multiple instances.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: Simply set the e.BringToForeground property to *false* in your event handler for the StartupNextInstance event.  Easy peasy.